# Android - AsyncTask inside Fragment doesn't work in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I created an AsyncTask to fetch scores. It shows the progressdialog for a split-sec and then disappears. The doInBackground method never gets executes. This task is called inside a fragment.

```
private class GetScore extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            final ProgressDialog show = progressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", yourName);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            scoreMap = ScoreCalc.getEngScore(yourName);
//            Toast.makeText(LoveActivity.this, engageMap.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String img) {
        }
    }
```

.
.
.
.
.
.
.

```
   private void confirmYes() {
     String s =mEditText.getText().toString();
        if(s.equals(""))
            return;
        new GetScore().execute();
    }
```

Help?

Answer (score 1):

use this asynctask class instead of your class.

```
public class GetScore extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    String method;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
    {
        method = arg0[0];
        return getData.callWebService(arg0[0], arg0[1]);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String xmlResponse)
    {
        if(xmlResponse.equals("") )
        {
            try{
                if(progDialog!=null && progDialog.isShowing()){
                    progDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){}
            Toast.
        }
        else
        {
            if (method.equals("methodname"))
            {

                MethodName(xmlResponse, "ResponseTag");
              
                try{
                    if(progDialog!=null && progDialog.isShowing()){
                        progDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }catch(Exception ex){}

                //What Ever Want to Do
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```